# polylines on google maps not accurate

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I have a transport android app and please try help me understand why the polylines appear to be moving irratically and sometimes completely off the road? Would it help to put bounds in that the new position can't jump more than a certain distance from the previous position?
Thanks.

Comment: The question is not clear at all..
Are you drawing polylines using GPS position? If so, the "not accurate" is not due to polylines but due to GPS position not accurate (there is indeed a variable accuracy that can be from 1mt to more than 10), if you need "snapping" on roads, you can use road api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/

Answer (score 1):

If you are displaying users' GPS locations as polyline on the maps, then you might want to snap it on the road with the Google newly published [Google Maps Roads API's snapToRoads function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap).

Basically what it does it to correct the GPS information onto the road. Since 1 picture worth 1000 words, see it yourself.

[image]

But currently they only provided a restful and javascript API, for Android, you need to call it through the restful services.

Google provided a github project for that, you can check its MainActivity out here:
 https://github.com/googlemaps/roads-api-samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/maps/roadsapi/MainActivity.java

Comment: Thank you both, Roads api definately the answer:)